# Enable opengl in vlc

Tags: vlc, opengl

How do I enable opengl in vlc as video output. It's not listed as a alternative.

Comment: do you mean hardware acceleration?

Comment: I don't know.. How do I check?

Comment: Use GPU Acceleration (experimental) in Input and codecs settings is this what you mean?

Comment: What is the advantage of using OpenGL? Why would it make things faster?

Answer (score 3):

1) Open VLC media player.

2) Click on Tools and select Preferences… .

3) mark "All" under "Show settings" in the bottom left corner

4) Expand Video and click on Output modules. Note that DON’T expand Output modules, just click on it.

5) Set Video output module to “OpenGL” or another setting you may want

Note: These steps are for V1.0.6 (Goldeneye) but I'm sure they'll be similar for other versions as well.

Comment: Guess I just like the old school look. I just noticed that if you don't select "All" under show settings that you can just click video and change the setting for the "Output" field.

Comment: I know how to select the video output, but like I said, it's not listed as an alternative, thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL output is not yet available in the Debian/Ubuntu packages.